# A way for saving data after closing a C program

Tags: c, persistence, persistent-storage

I want to use the c-programming language to built a small database for students. Only the admnistrator should enter delete or modify the data.  I have developed this program in C. But when i close my program, the data is lost. At the beginning i thought to store these data in files (like xml) but know i thinking to store these data on hardware (harddisk or sd-card). Is it possible? Any suggestions?

Comment: in any case you save it in a file

Comment: You have no choice but to save it as a file. Even databases are set of files. You can encrypt the file.

Comment: Flagged to close as *too broad*. This question does not address a *specific programming problem*. See: [*What's on-topic?*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Store your data in the Cloud. It is said nobody can touch it there (well, except the NSA, the KGB, Microsoft, Apple, and ten million script kiddie hackers).

Comment: Your question seems a bit puzzling. Do you want the people running your program to be able to change the data, or not?

Comment: .. The variety of answers in [this search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=persistent+data+in+memory+is%3Aq) suggests all solutions are highly OS dependent.

Comment: No, only an  administrator can change data. the Student can only see their data. not else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a separate program which acts as a "server" - that is, it runs continuously and communicates only through some sort of network interface - named pipes or TCP/IP or whatever. When your "client" program starts up it attempts to establish a connection with the server - if it does not find the server it starts it up and then establishes communications with it. Once the "server" is found the "client" requests any saved data from the "server", which the "server" then returns if it has any. When the "client" decides to shut down it first communicates with the "server", passing any data it wishes to save to the "server" which then stores it (perhaps in a file, perhaps in memory - the implementation is up to you).

Best of luck.

Comment: Ok, i habe two possibilities for saving data:                                                                                                            1) When the server stores in a file. How can i make it secure. Should i encrypt it? -> in this case i want that only the server  open it                                         2) if i want to store it in a harddisk. How can i do it?

Comment: @amitakCs Where do you think files are stored? Your question makes a curious distinction between "in files" and "on hardware". Don't worry about encryption until you have the basics sorted.

Comment: well, you can have an sd-card. you can write directly the data using a mapping function. Or you can create a file system and you store your data in form of files.